# Question on continuity and differentiability of min() and max() functions.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

**Question:**
$f(x)=x^2-2|x|$. Test the continuity of $g(x)$ in the interval $[-2,3]$ if $g(x)$ is defined as:

[image]

**attempt**:
$f(x)$ is defined as:[image]

But i am finding it difficult to understand $g(x)$. Generally in $min()$ functions, two or more functions are given and by using graphs, one can easily evaluate the function. Can you help me in evaluation $g(x)$? (rest of the question is easy)

Comment: Suggestion : plot f(x) first , it make easier to find max , min f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it'll be more clear with an example.

Let $x=-1$. We have $-2\leq -1 <0$ so we apply the first case: $g(x)=\min\{f(t)\, , -2\leq t\leq -1\}$.
$\forall t\in[-2,-1], f(t)=t^2+2t$. The minimum of $t^2+2t$ on the interval $[-2,-1]$ is $-1$ (I let you prove that). Hence $g(-1)=-1$.